# binding socket to specific interface

Tags: c, sockets, interface

I am trying to bind a socket to the specific (loopback) interface `lo` to prevent outside traffic from interfering with it:

```
int bind_socket(uint8_t *iface, uint8_t port) {
        int rv;
        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        rv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (rv < 0) return -1;
        if (setsockopt(rv, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, iface, strlen(iface)) < 0) {
                return -2;
        }
        bzero((char *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        if (bind(rv, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
                return -3;
        return rv;
}

...

int ss;
ss = bind_socket("lo", 100);
```

However, if I run `nmap localhost -e wlpXsX`, I should not be getting output indicating the socket is available through that interface. It is instead being reported as available; and I can't seem to be able to deduce why. Why is this interface globally available with a program designed to make it unavailable to all other interfaces?

Comment: XY problem? If you want a socket for local communication only, why do you use AF_INET socket at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> I am trying to bind a socket to the specific (loopback) interface

but you coded:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

`INADDR_ANY` (0.0.0.0) is *not* the loopback interface. You need to change it to `INADDR_LOOPBACK` (127.0.0.1) instead:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
```

Comment: He said he wanted to bind to the interface, not to the address. What about 127.0.0.2, which is also loopback.

Comment: This answer does not solve my problem. I can still detect the socket from other interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `nmap` was ignoring the interface switch, and routing its probes through the loopback interface anyway. Passing my LAN address as the target instead of `localhost`, and my LAN interface as the interface argument to `nmap` produced the intended result of the socket being invisible to outside the local host with the following source code:

```
int bind_lo(int port) {
        int rv;
        const char iface[] = "lo";
        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        rv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (rv < 0) return -1;
        bzero((char *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
        addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        if (bind(rv, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
                return -2;
        if (setsockopt(rv, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, iface, strlen(iface) + 1) < 0) {
                return -3;
        }
        return rv;
}
```